# gem5 build fails with "Error: can't find library python2.7 required by python"

Tags: ubuntu, gem5

I am trying to build gem5 but getting the following error. Can you please guide if some environment variable is need to be set? All the pre-requisite is installed.

```
$ uname -a
Linux i80pc93 4.4.0-148-generic #174~14.04.1-Ubuntu SMP Thu May 9 08:17:37 UTC 2019 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux

gem5$ scons build/ALPHA/gem5.opt 
scons: Reading SConscript files ... Checking for C library python2.7... no Error: can't find library python2.7 required by python

gem5$ gcc --version 
gcc (Ubuntu 4.8.5-4ubuntu8~14.04.2) 4.8.5 Copyright (C) 2015 Free Software Foundation, Inc. This is free software; see the source for copying conditions.  There is NO warranty; not even for MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE.


gem5$ python --version 
Python 2.7.6
```

I tried reinstalling python and gcc different versions, but it did not work. Please guide.

Comment: Please ask on mailing list, several related problems were answered lately due to python3 migration. Also give you gem5 version.

Comment: @CiroSantilli, thanks. The gem5 version is not recent one. I am using simulator from https://github.com/MPSLab-ASU/gemV/blob/master/README.md. 
I have build/compiled it on my same PC successfully, I don't know which parameters have changed on my system, I could not build/compile it again.

Comment: Could you check if your system has python3 installed and is it default python ? If so, you could try to set python 2 as default python and then try.